# Powershell pass command switches as variable

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to create a script that handle copy of folders and files.
i need to pass the switches '-recures -container' if it's a folder and nothing is it's a file.
is there a way to create a variable that will hold the '-recurse -container' and pass it to the command like this:

```
$copy_args = '-Recurse -container '
Copy-Item $tmptmp\$file -Destination \\$server\d$\$tmpprd\ $copy_args -Force
```

thanks
Mor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a technique called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6). You create a hashtable of the parameters you want to pass and then you use `@` with the variable name (instead of `$`) to indicate that you want to splat it in to the required cmdlets parameters:

```
$copy_args = @{
     Recurse = $true
     Container = $true
}

Copy-Item $tmptmp\$file -Destination \\$server\d$\$tmpprd\ @copy_args -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mark Wragg's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55022761/45375) recommends ***splatting***, which gives you the **most flexibility**.

As an aside:

- Setting `-Recurse` is sufficient in your case, because it *implies* `-Container`
- In fact, you can even use `-Recurse` *unconditionally*, because it is simply *ignored* if the source path is a *file*.

On occasion you may want to **conditionally pass a switch *directly***, without the added verbosity of splatting.

Given that the syntax - `-SomeSwitch:$boolVar` or `-SomeSwitch:(<boolExpression>)` (optionally with whitespace after `:`) - isn't obvious, let me demonstrate:

Using a Boolean *variable*:

```
# The source path.
$sourcePath = $tmptmp\$file

# Set the Boolean value that will turn the -Recurse switch on / off.
$doRecurse = Test-Path -PathType Container $sourcePath # $true if $sourcePath is a dir.

# Use -Recurse:$doRecurse
Copy-Item -Recurse:$doRecurse $sourcePath -Destination \\$server\d$\$tmpprd\ -Force
```

Alternatively, using a Boolean *expression*:

```
Copy-Item -Recurse:(Test-Path -PathType Container $sourcePath) $sourcePath -Destination \\$server\d$\$tmpprd\ -Force
```

Note that the `:` to separate the parameter name from the argument is a necessity in the case of a *switch* parameter, so as to indicate that the argument is intended for the *switch* (which normally do *not* take an argument) rather than being a separate, positional argument.

**Caveat**: Both in this case and with splatting **passing an effective `$false` to a switch is technically *not* the same as *omitting* the switch, and there are situations where the difference matters**.
Read on to learn more.

---

Technically, a cmdlet or advanced function can distinguish between an *omitted* switch and one with a `$false` *argument* via the automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable, which contains a dictionary of all explicitly passed parameters.

In the case of **the common `-Confirm` parameter**, this distinction is used *intentionally* - which is *atypical*.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```
# Sample advanced function that supports -Confirm with a medium impact level.
function foo { 
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
  param() 

  if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess('dummy')) { 'do it' }  
}

# Invocation *with -Confirm* prompts unconditionally.
foo -Confirm  # ditto with -Confirm:$true

# Invocation *without -Confirm*:
# Whether you'll be prompted depends on the value of the $ConfirmPreference
# variable: If the value is 'Medium' or 'Low', you'll be prompted.
foo

# Invocation with *-Confirm:$false* NEVER prompts,
# irrespective of the $ConfirmPreference value.
foo -Confirm:$false
```